# Dialog fragment changes all other options menu

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-coordinatorlayout

My android app contains one main activity, two Fragment and one Dialog Fragment.

> Main activity has an option menu.
>
> Main Fragment use the main activity's option menu.
>
> Second fragment has another option menu.
>
> From second fragment, i can open the Dialog Fragment which contain
>   another set of option menu.

But when close the Dialog Fragment, option menus of all other fragment and activity are changed to that of Dialog Fragment.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

SecondFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_second, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

MyDialogFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_dialog, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: Try calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreateView()` of SecondFragment and `onCreate()` of MainActiivty.

Comment: Ya I have already done it. But not solved

Comment: add invalidateOptionsMenu() in onResume()...

Answer (score 0):

Call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in your second fragment.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()):

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The
>   `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` method will be called the next time it needs
>   to be displayed.

In SecondFragment:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: It's also not useful...sorry